# How can the Boussinesq Approximation simplify the general form of the temperature equation for fluids?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics, convection

In *Transport Phenomena* by Bird, Stewart, Lightfoot (2nd edition), on page 337 (11.2–5), the equation for the change in temperature is derived:
$$
\rho\hat{C}_{p}\frac{DT}{Dt}=-\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{q}\right)-\underline{\underline{\tau}}^{T}\mathbf{:}\nabla\mathbf{v}-\left(\frac{\partial\ln\rho}{\partial\ln T}\right)\frac{Dp}{Dt}.
$$
I want to justify dropping this term
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial\ln\rho}{\partial\ln T}\right)\frac{Dp}{Dt}
\end{equation}
when the Boussinesq approximation is assumed. That is when density is a linear function of temperature: $\rho=\rho_0[1-\alpha\left(T-T_0)\right]$, where
$$\alpha=-\frac{1}{\rho_0}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial T}\bigg|_{T=T_0}.$$
Presumably the way to proceed is to show that $\partial\ln\rho/\partial\ln T \to 0$? This is where I am stuck, any help is very much appreciated.